# Como removo tudo depois da primeira palavra?

Tags: cmd, algoritmo-de-busca, batch, replace

Como remover tudo após a primeira palavra em cada linha num arquivo de texto contendo o caractere **`pipe`**?

Ele funciona para remoção de caracteres simples/comuns, mas não tem funcionado  para remover o caractere  **<kbd>|</kbd>**  ( **`pipe`**  ) do arquivo de texto.

```
blue | a
blueemail@free.com:pass | a
fear under dark | a 
123 | a 
abc 123 | a 
hustlerman | a 
yellow | a 
123 | a 
email@net.br:senha | a 
conta@com.br:guypassord | a 
12345678-king-man | a 
rabaman | a 
abc | a
```

**Estou usando o seguinte código:**

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set /p txtfile=Text File Name: 
    Echo.
set /p "search=Search for: "
    Echo.
set /p "replace=Replace to: "

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%txtfile%.txt" ^& break ^> "%txtfile%.txt" ') do (
      set "line=%%i"
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      >>"%txtfile%.tmp" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
      endlocal
    )

ren "%txtfile%".tmp "%txtfile%".txt 

pause
```

> **Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sem editar** serve apenas para arquivos com layout igual do seu exemplo, onde temos o **`pipe`** como delimitador, para outro delimitadore, edite o commando **`set _delimiter`**, e para o ***caracteres especiais***, imagino que já saibas, porém posto para os demais visitantes, caso estes não saibam, adicione o **`^`** antes do caracter, como exemplo: **`^|`**, **`^&`**, **`^^`**, etc..

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion && color 0a

set /p "'_delimiter=^|"<nul

echo. && set /p "txtfile=Text File Name: "

copy "%txtfile%" "%temp%\%txtfile%.tmp" /y

type nul >"%temp%\%txtfile%_crop.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims=%_delimiter%" %%i in ('type "%temp%\%txtfile%.tmp"') do (

   set "_line=%%~i"
   echo/!_line!>>"%temp%\%txtfile%_crop.txt"

)

move /y "%temp%\%txtfile%_crop.txt" "%txtfile%"

del /q /f  "%temp%\%txtfile%.tmp"

pause
```

Comment: Obrigado, desculpa a demora, ajudou bastante!

Comment: Trankilo tchê!! Sem pavôro!! Obrigado!